# Differences between csi and csc (Chicken Scheme)

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

Why is the function `compose` defined in the interpreter `csi` and not in the compiler `csc`?  I know I can easily define it by myself, but I was just wondering why there is such a  difference.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `compose` procedure is from the unit `data-structures` (see [the manual](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Unit%20data-structures#compose) or [API docs](http://api.call-cc.org/doc/data-structures/compose)). You can load it by typing `(use data-structures)`.

As to why it's available in `csi` and not in `csc` by default is a bit of a hairy implementation detail; the `csi` interpreter simply needs to load a few modules itself in order to provide an interpreter environment.  Due to the way it's implemented, everything that's loaded by `csi` also becomes available at the top-level.  In CHICKEN 5, this situation has improved quite a bit and the interpreter starts with a clean top-level environment.

So what this means in practice is that you should always explicitly `(use)` all modules that your program needs, to ensure that it works in compiled mode as well as interpreted mode. Instead of putting your program at the top-level environment, you can also wrap your entire program inside a [module](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Modules).  Modules always have a completely clean environment, so there will be no difference when you compile it versus when you interpret it.